# cv2.circle produces diamond shape for small radii

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, drawing, interpolation

I want to draw ~5M circles in a random range of 0.25 to 500.0 (values get rounded to int to be able to draw it).

However, for circles of all sizes, there is a litle "spike" at each side.
I tried using some interploation method but the circles get warped.

[image: lineType comparison]

code to generate the image:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
a = np.zeros((20, 25), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.circle(a, center=(3, 5), radius=1, thickness=-1, color=55)
cv2.circle(a, center=(3, 14), radius=1, thickness=-1, color=55, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.circle(a, center=(10, 5), radius=2, thickness=-1, color=255)
cv2.circle(a, center=(10, 14), radius=2, thickness=-1, color=255, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.circle(a, center=(19, 5), radius=3, thickness=-1, color=125)
cv2.circle(a, center=(19, 14), radius=3, thickness=-1, color=125, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

i tried skimage.draw.disk() which looked more circular, but it was way too slow (~2d instead of 1h exec time)

Comment: if you need accurate circles, you'll have to draw them yourself. give aggdraw a look, or whatever PIL has for drawing. or pick a GUI library and see what they can do. -- this defect in OpenCV is known. its LINE_AA mode is totally off in terms of line width. regardless of mode, it draws ovals (also apparent in `cv.getStructuringElement`). it draws a polygon as an approximation of a circle.  the dangly pixels might be due to lack of thought put into the implementation. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22042#issuecomment-1586258762

Comment: you say it takes you 1 hour to 2 days to draw your 5 million circles... perhaps you need to think about hardware-accelerated drawing (a scene with 5 million instances of a circle, should draw fairly quickly on a graphics card). or an algorithmic solution. sort those things by size, put them into a quadtree. then you can decide which can be drawn in parallel. -- don't draw each individually. draw each common radius once, then overlay the drawing in each position you need it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for hinting the issue. 
I want to generate the dead leaves pattern / spilled coins pattern in a huge resolution (64*HD). It works by drawing circles of random radii for a random position. The end condition is if all pixels are overlapped by at least one circle. There is the approach to only draw the foreground circles after generating a gigantic list of circles, but thats not quite easy to implement since i dont know where the circle border will be. Anyways, i am not happy with how the circles will be drawn later on.